# How can I solve my strange no space left on device on fedora?

Tags: fedora, filesystems, virtualbox, btrfs

I run a fedora 38 system on virtual box (7.0). Now I have a "no space left on device" problem.

```
# dnf list *docker*
Fedora 38 - x86_64 - Updates                                                                                                                         27 kB/s |  15 kB     00:00    
Fedora 38 - x86_64 - Updates                                                                                                                         26 kB/s |  15 kB     00:00    
Fehler: Failed to download metadata for repo 'updates': Cannot create /var/cache/dnf/updates-b7ba662710b98f1a/tmpdir.wb9fEj/metalink.xml: Auf dem Gerät ist kein Speicherplatz mehr verfügbar
```

But "df -h" show there is enough (3.6G on /) space.

```
# df -h
Dateisystem    Größe Benutzt Verf. Verw% Eingehängt auf
devtmpfs        4,0M       0  4,0M    0% /dev
tmpfs           1,9G       0  1,9G    0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           762M    9,5M  752M    2% /run
/dev/sda3        19G     16G  3,6G   82% /
tmpfs           1,9G     16K  1,9G    1% /tmp
/dev/sda3        19G     16G  3,6G   82% /home
/dev/sda2       974M    258M  650M   29% /boot
fedora_shared   466G    374G   93G   81% /vbox_shared
tmpfs           381M    176K  381M    1% /run/user/1000
```

and here are the details

```
# fdisk -l /dev/sda
GPT-PMBR-Größenunterschied (41943039 != 62914559) wird durch »write« korrigiert.
Die GPT-Sicherungstabelle befindet sich nicht am Ende des Gerätes.
Festplatte /dev/sda: 30 GiB, 32212254720 Bytes, 62914560 Sektoren
Festplattenmodell: VBOX HARDDISK   
Einheiten: Sektoren von 1 * 512 = 512 Bytes
Sektorgröße (logisch/physikalisch): 512 Bytes / 512 Bytes
E/A-Größe (minimal/optimal): 512 Bytes / 512 Bytes
Festplattenbezeichnungstyp: gpt
Festplattenbezeichner: 1B8AA65F-1078-4C62-9AE3-91BD557AC875

Gerät       Anfang     Ende Sektoren Größe Typ
/dev/sda1     2048     4095     2048    1M BIOS boot
/dev/sda2     4096  2101247  2097152    1G Linux-Dateisystem
/dev/sda3  2101248 41940991 39839744   19G Linux-Dateisystem
```

What is my mistake?

Some diagnostics:

```
# df -i
Dateisystem     Inodes IBenutzt   IFrei IUse% Eingehängt auf
devtmpfs        482157      505  481652    1% /dev
tmpfs           487086        1  487085    1% /dev/shm
tmpfs           819200      938  818262    1% /run
/dev/sda3            0        0       0     - /
tmpfs          1048576       39 1048537    1% /tmp
/dev/sda3            0        0       0     - /home
/dev/sda2        65536      394   65142    1% /boot
fedora_shared     1000  -999000 1000000     - /vbox_shared
tmpfs            97417      165   97252    1% /run/user/1000

# btrfs filesystem usage /
Overall:
    Device size:          19.00GiB
    Device allocated:         19.00GiB
    Device unallocated:        1.00MiB
    Device missing:          0.00B
    Device slack:            0.00B
    Used:             15.47GiB
    Free (estimated):          3.37GiB  (min: 3.37GiB)
    Free (statfs, df):         3.37GiB
    Data ratio:               1.00
    Metadata ratio:           2.00
    Global reserve:       60.30MiB  (used: 0.00B)
    Multiple profiles:              no

Data,single: Size:17.97GiB, Used:14.59GiB (81.22%)
   /dev/sda3      17.97GiB

Metadata,DUP: Size:518.00MiB, Used:448.48MiB (86.58%)
   /dev/sda3       1.01GiB

System,DUP: Size:8.00MiB, Used:16.00KiB (0.20%)
   /dev/sda3      16.00MiB

Unallocated:
   /dev/sda3       1.00MiB
```

Comment: Note: it would be easier (also for look to google the error messages) if you get errors in English. Just prepend `LANG=C ` *your command*.

Comment: why  there're home and root mounted on the same partition `/dev/sda3` ?

Comment: @D'ArcyNader they’re different subvolumes on a btrfs volume, probably. That’s also why they show up as having no inodes.

Comment: Can you also please add output of `btrfs filesystem usage /`?

Comment: @StephenKitt thank you !

Comment: @D'ArcyNader this is the fedora default partion & mounttab. I had used the quick and dirty installation - it's not perfect - you are right!

Comment: @VojtechTrefny I add the information. I also think it's a special problem of btrfs and the 0 inodes. But I have not a solution!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I try

```
btrfs balance start -dusage=5
```

it helped! After this I deleted some of not needed content and my system worked now again.

It's a problem of the btrfs. I'm not a expert but this help me:

- https://serverfault.com/a/784979
- https://www.suse.com/support/kb/doc/?id=000018807
- https://discussion.fedoraproject.org/t/running-out-of-inodes-on-btrfs/75356/3